# Sending Xaml/WPF Canvas to a WCF service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xaml, canvas

I want to save Canvas created in WPF by Xaml as an image by the WCF service.

```
    ImageServiceClient client = new ImageServiceClient();
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        client.SaveImage(canvas); // Here the exception shows.
    }
```

Xaml part:

```
    <Canvas Name="canvas">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Something..." VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Canvas>
```

This should send Canvas as a parameter to the method in the WCF service but throws this exception to me:

> "Additional information: There was an error while trying to serialize
>   parameter http://tempuri.org/:o. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Canvas' with data contract name
>   'Canvas:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Windows.Controls'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are
>   using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to
>   the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details."

And I did not find any work around for this problem.
My question is whether it is possible at all and if so how?

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: You wouldn't want to pass a Canvas to a WCF service. Instead, use a RenderTargetBitmap in your WPF application to create a bitmap from the Canvas. Then probably pass the bitmap to the service.

Comment: I know I can do that but will bitmap transfer last much longer for say 10,000 images than using Canvas as a parameter?

Comment: That depends on how you serialize and deserialize your Canvas. Do you have an idea how you want to do that? Write XAML, send it as string, on the server side recreate the visual tree from the XAML?

Comment: I have no idea, because after string serialization you can not deserialize it after back on the server (or I can not). Is there a possibility of Canvas serialization/deserialization at all?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, and I greatly dislike the idea in general. UI elements shouldn't be serialized and passed to a service application. You may perhaps create kind of an abstract model that represents the UI and can be interchanged between service and client application.

Comment: Ok, so I will drop this idea, thank you for your help, and your time.